# Search file names that contain a string

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

I have a module named `flume` and file names that include that module name, like `flumeIndexController`, `flumePlugin` etc. Now I've decided to rename the module to `oozie` so I want to have these files renamed to include new module's name like `oozieIndexController`, `ooziePlugin`.

How can I get a list of files than include the `flume` string (in file name) possibly using built-in search or through any other option?

Comment: `Edit | Find | Find in Path...` ??

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to be searching for the string in a file's contents instead of in file names

Comment: `Navigate | File...` then

Comment: Yes, something like that, but with a possibility to search only in a particular folder (like how it can be configured in Find in Path function) and show the list in search tab. It seems that there is no such option.

Comment: **1)** *"but with a possibility to search only in a particular folder"* You can do a post-filter (exclude unwanted results after) .. or you can just type leading part of the path... **2)** *"and show the list in search tab"* this window has **only 2 buttons** -- that's a HINT (I'm sure you will figure it out; if not -- try clicking on them)

Comment: Thanks, yeah, that's pretty close to what I was looking for. Can you post as an answer and I'll accept it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Navigate | File...`** <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + N</kbd> using Default keymap.

You can narrow your search results (just specify parts of the path, e.g. `/abc/` and it will show results in a folders that match such pattern/abbreviation). Alternatively -- just do a post-filtering by excluding unwanted results (see below).

This window has only 2 buttons -- one of which will display results in a more traditional and permanent "Search results" tool window (the one that you see when you do `Find in Path` and alike).